# Submit onclick value to function

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to submit the value of my onClick to a function. It works properly if the "li" is manually coded. However, it doesn't work if the "li" is in the loop and it was appended in a div.

Here's the code I've already tried:(also tried to change ' to " in oncliclick=myFunction('i'))

```
<div id="side_menubar">
    <ul>
    <script>

    <? var menu = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id here").getSheetByName("Menu");

   var range = menu.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
   var lRow = range.filter(String).length;?> 
     <?for(var i = 2; i <= lRow; i++){?>
     $('#side_menubar').append($('<li class="menu" onclick="myFunction('i')"><?= menu.getRange("B" + i).getValues(); ?></li>'))
         <? } ?>    
   function myFunction(x) {
   document.getElementById("content_header").innerHTML = "x";
   document.getElementById("id01").style.display = "block";
   }   
   </script>
   </ul>    
   </div>
```

I expect that the value in the onClick should be submitted to the function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use these very much

but I think this one

`$('#side_menubar').append($('<li class="menu" onclick="myFunction('i')">`

needs to be like this

`$('#side_menubar').append($('<li class="menu" onclick="myFunction(<?=i?>)">`

- [Example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets)

Comment: Hi Cooper thanks for the idea. It doesn't work but when i change it to this

Answer (score 0):

Hi Cooper thanks for the idea. It doesn't work but when i change it to this it works:
`$('#side_menubar').append($('<li class="menu" onclick="myFunction(<?=i?>)">`

I just removed the single quote because I think it breaks or it reads as a closing  quote for the li for append.

Comment: The answer above works and it will submit the value in the function.  function myFunction(x) {

  document.getElementById("content_header").innerHTML = x;
}    However, when i tried to get the text value using this: 
  function myFunction(x) {

  document.getElementById("content_header").innerHTML = <?= menu.getRange("B" + x).getValues(); ?>;
}  I would like to clarify if this is allowed?

Comment: You can put the HTML there like that but it’s not gonna work because those scriptlets are evaluated on the server before It’s sent to the browser to render the HTML that’s what the evaluate does at the end of the HTML service declaration.

Comment: Is that mean there's no solution to my issue? Or is there any alternative for that?

Comment: You could is to load it on the server before it's rendered on the browser or generate it on the server with  by calling a server side function window.onload or $(function(){});  You can call the  server with google.script.run.onSuccessHandler().serversidefunctionname() and have that function return the html and load it with Javascript.  You should read the Google Apps Script Documentation.